# Do z-indexes no longer work after a -webkit transform?

Tags: css

I'm trying to move some panes (divs) under a menu (div) using a `-webkit-transform: translate(-100px)`. Hard to explain, have a look instead: http://jsfiddle.net/neWXa/7/

Trouble is, I can't get the panes to go under the menu div. I figured I would use z-indexes, but it doesn't seem to work.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.main { z-index: -1; }
```

That does it for me. :)

Comment: I don't see that the panes are nested inside '#menu'.

Comment: Edited, my browser didn't DL the whole html for some reason the first time.

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` only work for positioned elements.

`.menu` is not positioned, thus `z-index` has no effect on it.